# Menu contribution in pure e4 eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, e4

I am writing an eclipse plugin and I want to stick to the e4 programming model as far as possible.
First thing I want to do are menu and toolbar contributions but I am already stuck. I defined an extension in my `plugin.xml`:

```
<extension id="sampleid1" point="org.eclipse.e4.workbench.model">
    <fragment apply="always" uri="xmi/myplugin.e4xmi" />
</extension>
```

Inisde the `myplugin.e4xmi` I tried to define both a `menu` as well as a `menuContribution` fragment along with a command and a handler fragment, but everything leads to the following log output:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 1 0 2014-08-25 09:22:41.476
!MESSAGE Nothing to merge for "platform:/plugin/net.mysample/xmi/myplugin.e4xmi"
```

Am I missing something? Or is it not yet possible to write pure e4 plugins for the eclipse IDE? If so, what parts of e4 should I use, where should I stick to 3.x API? I already implemented some views and found the injection based programming quite comfortable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be related with [bug 376486](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=376486):

### [Model] Eclipse 4 IDE not extendable via fragments or processors

> Currently the Eclipse 4.2 IDE cannot be extended via fragments or processors which makes it difficult for Eclipse plug-in projects to use the new programming model.
>
> This is due to the fact that the processing of fragments and processors is done bevor the compatibility layer, e.g. the conversion of `plugin.xml` to the model is not done and therefore these elements cannot get extended.

---

[This thread](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/635683/) illustrated the same issue:

> Fragments are not yet supported in combination with the compatibility layer.
> The reason for that is the order of initialization.
> **The compatiblity extension points (such as "views") in Luna will support to add pure e4 views, though**.

But also:

> so Luna has released. Is it possible to contribute toolbar with fragments via model?
> I use Eclipse Luna and E4 last updates but got the same message as described by topic starter:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 1 0 2014-07-20 18:43:30.248
!MESSAGE Nothing to merge for "platform:/plugin/.../fragment.e4xmi"
```

---

There is [a thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/e4-dev/msg08421.html) about a way to import e4 elements into *any* E3 based application to reach "true mixed mode" (i.e. use E4 programming model in E3 based apps like the IDE)
Project [`E4Examples/importworkbenchbridge`](https://github.com/E4Examples/importworkbenchbridge).

Comment: I tried the workaround in [link](https://github.com/E4Examples/importworkbenchbridge), but it does not work with fragments properly and uses a lot of (unsafe) casts and unreleased API, so I guess I'll have to wait for Mars for a proper "pure e4" plugin.